# Gnuplot - Graphic appears and disappears when zooming

Tags: graphics, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot some graphics in gnuplot, and I find out that canvas doesn't show the whole curve. It shows different graphics for different zooms.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What could I do to solve this?

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed

Comment: Is the curve a function or point data from a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try increasing the number of points drawn by gnuplot?

use set samples 10000.

but be careful, it might slow down your process.